# Getting make error 127 after compile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to teach myself gnuMake after learning the basics of C++

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 equivalent (elementary os)

And I am getting the error (full output of make run):

```
g++ ./main.o -w  -o test
This is a test!
/bin/sh: 1: This: not found
make: *** [exe] Error 127
```

My Makefile:

```
CC=g++
SRC=$(shell find -name '*.cpp')
OBJS= $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
EXEC=test
FLAGS= -w
LINKS=

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $*.cpp -o $*.o

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(FLAGS) $(LINKS) -o $(EXEC)

all: $(EXEC)

exe: 
    $(shell ./$(EXEC))

run: all exe

clean: 
    rm -rf *.o $(EXEC)
```

This is a combination of taking basic make tutorials and reading Makefiles in github

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "This is a test!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Pretty Basic, but will be extending it to help learn to use and extend my Makefile.  Now I can see the program compiles and runs, but I get the error after the run.

I searched for Make error 127 and that seems to output that error for many things, but I did not see a definition for the error, or a similar issue to mine.

Comment: As a style note, you probably want to move the `all:` ahead of the `$(EXEC):` target. When `make` is invoked with no arguments, it picks the first target in the file as the goal. Traditionally, that would be `all:`. In this case, the effect would be the same, but you might want to extend `all:` to cover other programs, build documentation, or also run tests.

Comment: While looking at the overall style, I personally would be careful about using `rm -rf` since that could easily reach and delete unintended files. I lean towards having `clean:` delete only things that I know are created by the build, so I would write `rm $(OBJS)` rather than `rm -rf *.o`.

Comment: Thanks @RBerteig... I will start using `rm` that way... And I'm glad you told me that about `all:` I thought make looked for `all:` when no arguments are called

Comment: Something else to explore as you learn about make in general and GNU make in particular is the [extremely rich set of predefined rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) and conventional macros for options used by those rules. `%.o: %.cpp` has a default definition, and it uses macros named `CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS` and more; in this case the compilation has the form `$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c` where `CXX` will default to `g++`. The same applies to linking an executable as long as at least one source file has the same base name as the executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(shell ./$(EXEC)` is incorrect.

That is having make run the executable and then replacing `$(shell ./$(EXEC)` with the output from the executable and then trying to run that as the command in the recipe.

You just want

```
exec: $(EXEC)
    ./$<
```

Comment: Right, sorry, habit of using the target for things like this.