# Why am I getting this error when I run my Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to run a makefile to execute my code, but it returns this error:

`make: *** [makefile:8: run] Error 127`

Makefile code:

```
main: *.o
    g++ -o main *.cpp

*.o: *.h *.cpp
    g++ -g -c *.cpp

run:
    ./main

clean:
    rm ./*.o main
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting make error 127 after compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300984/getting-make-error-127-after-compile)

Comment: @user438383 No, it does not

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36368057/5784757

Comment: @user438383 I looked at this previously and it wasn't helpful

Comment: OK - you should include what you looked at in your question so your post isn't flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: I guess problem may be caused by environment or way make is being invoked. On my machine I get this error when running `make clean run` and don't get it when I just run `make`

Comment: Make doesn't use `*` as wildcards and even if it did, you can't use wildcards as a dependency. What `make` manual are you working from?

Comment: Please include the entire output, not just the error line from make.  This error is simply make telling you that the command it invoked exited with an error code 127.  You don't show us what command make invoked, or any errors that it might have shown, so there's no way we can tell you what is wrong.

Comment: However, @Galik is correct, you can't use `*.o` as a prerequisite.  The problem is not that make can't support wildcards as a dependency, however.  The problem is that when make starts up there are no files matching `*.o` (because make hasn't built any yet) and all targets and prerequisites are expanded as the makefile is parsed, not later when the rule is run.  So you can only wildcard _source_ files, not built files.  Anyway, your recipe for `main` doesn't even use any object files: it compiles all the source files.  So you could use `*.cpp` as prerequisites but not `*.o`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that Makefile doesn't like your asterisks. I would recommend leveraging matchers '%' instead.

Please see:
[How to properly use % or * (asterisk) symbols as a placeholder in makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155241/how-to-properly-use-or-asterisk-symbols-as-a-placeholder-in-makefile)